# TextFormating.NewLine not honored in Field Maps

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I have an arcade expression that removes null fields from my pop up in AGOL Map Viewer Beta. I need the same pop up settings to also be honored in Field Maps. When using the TextFormatting.NewLine or "\n" all my fields get concated into one line in Field Maps. Here are the expressions I've tried using:

```
var returnstring = TextFormatting.NewLine

    for (var i in $feature) {
        if (!isEmpty($feature[i])){
          returnstring = returnstring + i + ": " + $feature[i] + TextFormatting.NewLine
      }
    }
    return returnstring
```

And this expression:

```
var result = "";
if (!IsEmpty($feature.ABUNDANCE)) {
    result += "\n" + "Abundance: " + $feature.ABUNDANCE;
}
if (!IsEmpty($feature.OCCSTATUS)) {
    result += "\n" + "Occurence Status: " + $feature.OCCSTATUS;
}
if (!IsEmpty($feature.COMNAME)) {
    result += "\n" + "Common Name: " + $feature.COMNAME;
}

return result;
```

In field maps the popup window looks like

```
`Abundance: 2 Occurence Status: 2 Common
Name: Example`
```

Anyone know of a workaround? I'm trying to just hide null values from my pop up and not have blank spaces between rows.

Desired results:

```
`Abundance: 2
 Occurence Status: 2 
 Common Name: Example`
```

Comment: Have you seen this [thread](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-field-maps-questions/arcade-expression-in-pop-up-error-15/td-p/1017409)? They use concatenate().

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to get new lines.

try the HTML Line Break `"<br/>"` [image] instead of `"\n"`

The Web Map looks ugly, but Field Maps looks good which is what I needed.